# What is release of jQuery is compatible with jQuery UI 1.7.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

what is release of jQuery is compatible with jQuery UI 1.7.2 ?

Edit: sorry i mean if jQuery UI 1.7.2 is compatible with jQuery 1.2.6.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3):

When you download jQuery UI, it comes with a compatible version of jQuery Core. For example, jQuery UI 1.7.3 shipped with jQuery 1.3.2. (I suspect that jQuery UI 1.7.2 also shipped with jQuery 1.3.2.)

Answer (score 1):

It says in the [jQuery UI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download) that 1.7.3 is compatible with jQuery 1.3+, so no, jQuery 1.2.6 is probably not going to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and checked jquery UI 1.7.2 package, it shipped with jquery 1.3.2. So `NO` if you are expecting full support